# What is the geometric interpretation behind the method of exact differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Given an equation in the form $M(x)dx + N(y)dy = 0$ we test that the partial derivative of $M$ with respect to $y$ is equal to the partial derivative of $N$ with respect to $x$. If they are equal, then the equation is exact. What is the geometric interpretation of this?

Further more to solve the equation we may integrate $M(x) dx$ or $N(y)dy$, whichever we like better, and then add a constant as a function in terms of the constant variable and solve this.

e.g. If $f(x) = 3x^2$ then $F(x) = x^3 + g(y)$.

After we have our integral we set its partial differential with respect to the other variable our other given derivative and solve for $g(y)$. I have done the entire homework assignment correctly, but I have no clue why I am doing these steps. What is the geometric interpretation behind this method, and how does it work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Great question.  The idea is that $(M(x), N(y))$ defines a [vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field), and the condition you're checking is equivalent (on $\mathbb{R}^2$) to the vector field being [conservative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field), i.e. being the [gradient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) of some scalar function $p$ called the potential.  Common physical examples of conservative vector fields include gravitational and electric fields, where $p$ is the gravitational or electric potential.

Geometrically, being conservative is equivalent to the [curl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)) vanishing.  It is also equivalent to the condition that [line integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) between two points depend only on the beginning and end points and not only on the path chosen.  (The connection between this and the curl is [Green's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem).)

The differential equation $M(x) \, dx + N(y) \, dy = 0$ is then equivalent to the condition that $p$ is a constant, and since this is not a differential equation it is a much easier condition to work with.  The analogous one-variable statement is that $M(x) \, dx = 0$ is equivalent to $\int M(x) \, dx = \text{const}$.  Geometrically, the solutions to $M(x) \, dx + N(y) \, dy = 0$ are therefore the [level curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set) of the potential, which are always orthogonal to its gradient.  The most well-known example of this is probably the diagram of the electric field and the level curves of the electrostatic potential around a dipole.  This is one way to interpret the expression $M(x) \, dx + N(y) \, dy = 0$; it is precisely equivalent to the "dot product" of $(M(x), N(y)$ and $(dx, dy)$ being zero, where you should think of $(dx, dy)$ as being an infinitesimal displacement along a level curve.

(For those in the know, I am ignoring the distinction between vector fields and 1-forms and also the distinction between closed forms and exact forms.)

Comment: At the end of the first paragraph, what were you meaning to say? "I am being slightly biased?"

Comment: @Trevor: whoops.  I meant to say what I said at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look up the wiki article on [exact differentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential) and [inexact differentials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential). The famous physical quantity which you cannot write as an exact differential is heat.